# SQL. Can not rollback transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I try to use transactions to delete few lines from my table. I use three times command delete, two of them are OK and third contains mistakes. I want to create save point and commit dropping of 2 objects. But I got an error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE ID = 101; --OK

DELETE FROM employee
WHERE Name = 'James'; --OK

SAVE TRANSACTION point_1;

DELETE FROM employee
WHERE ID = '11a'; --letters are not allowed
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION point_1
    PRINT 'Error! Not all employees were deleted from database.'
END CATCH
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

I tried this way:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE ID = 101;

DELETE FROM employee
WHERE Name = 'James';

SAVE TRANSACTION point_1;

BEGIN TRY
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE ID = '11a';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    if XACT_STATE () = -1
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    if XACT_STATE () = 1 and @@TRANCOUNT = 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    if XACT_STATE () = 1 and @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION point_1
PRINT 'Error! Not all employees were deleted from database.'
END CATCH
```

There are no errors this time, but first two objects are not deleted. Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Transaction Error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488149/sql-transaction-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-su)

Comment: My query is going thru uncommittable state. How can I return to my savepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `SET XACT_ABORT ON` on the session. If your code is inside a trigger, then this setting is ON by default.

Try your code with `SET XACT_ABORT OFF`.