# Try catch inside while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to implement try-catch block, so that if any error occurs in the sp call, then the status column is updated to error. But I am getting the following error.

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    id INT IDENTITY, 
    col1 VARCHAR(100), 
    status VARCHAR(50)
) 

DECLARE @batch_size INT 
SET @batch_size = 5 

INSERT INTO table2 
    SELECT TOP(500) col1 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE status IS NULL 
    ORDER BY id 

SELECT TOP(1) 
    @id = id, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 
FROM table2 
ORDER BY id 

WHILE @@rowcount > 0  
BEGIN 
begin try
     EXEC SP param1 = col1, param2 = col2 

     UPDATE table1 
     SET status = 'closed' 
end try
begin catch
   UPDATE table1 
     SET status = 'error' 
end catch
     SELECT TOP(1) @id = id, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 
     FROM table2 
     WHERE id > @id 
     ORDER BY id 
END
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488149/sql-transaction-error-the-current-transaction-cannot-be-committed-and-cannot-su)

Comment: This line has syntax errors.  EXEC SP - more information is needed to diagnose the issue.  Please upload a working example w/o begin/try.

Comment: same sample code was used by me to ask question related to batching. This question is related to try catch block.