# Insert in TABLE_A shouldn't fail if something fails in trigger. How?

Tags: sql-server

I have TABLE_A and on another database I Have TABLE_B. There is a trigger on TABLE_A to replicate insertions from TABLE_A to TABLE_B. If something fails on the trigger the insertions on TABLE_A should not fail (I have no control over TABLE_A, columns can be removed or renamed, etc...).

I'm working with SQL Server 2005.

I've tryed TRY ... CATCH but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an `AFTER INSERT`?  Also what did you try with `TRY...CATCH`?

Comment: I have no code in the CATCH to ignore the error and proceed, but everithing is rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using triggers - is an atomic operation - it can either complete without errors or fail the whole operation (INSERT+trigger). Try to use other variants, such as using SP for adding records to tables.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884334/tsql-try-catch-transaction-in-trigger).

Ultimately though, triggers run inside of an implicit transaction which runs counter to what you are looking for. A different approach to this problem might be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

I would move this to an async-style operation.  Have the change operations to TABLE_A queue a request to copy the appropriate records and have a separate process monitor that queue.  That way you are not tying the replication process into the insert transaction, only the queueing of the replication operation is tied into the insert transaction.

Comment: How would that queuing process be implemented?

Comment: @Neves Since the data obviously cannot be in perfect sync (otherwise you'd want the trigger to fail), some degree of difference is acceptable.  The question would be how long that period should be.  If the volume of changes is low, you can use sp_start_job to start a job, or you can write to a table and have a regularly scheduled job look at the table and perform the sync.  I'm not sure there is such a thing as a high performance update outside of the transaction - all would involve making another connection outside the transaction (like through SQLCLR).