# XACT_Abort = ON issue with Try Catch

Tags: sql-server, exception

I have this piece of script:

```
Create Table AA (ID int identity(1,1), Col1 varchar(10))
Create Table BB (ID int identity(1,1), Col1 varchar(10))
GO
Create proc p6
as
insert into AA
(Col1)
Values('')

GO

Create Trigger [dbo].[TR_AA] on [dbo].[AA]
After insert
As
--Set XACT_Abort off
Select 1/0
GO

Begin Try
Begin Tran

Select @@TRANCOUNT

exec p6

Commit Tran
End Try
Begin Catch
  insert into BB(Col1)Values('')
  Select * from AA
  --Select XACT_STATE()

  Rollback Tran
End Catch

Select Count(*) from AA

GO
```

When I run this code i am getting this error:

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support
>   operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

I already know what causes this issue.

The example is just an example. But I have lots of Business logics inside the trigger that I can't move them out.

So one workaround would be to put `Set XACT_Abort off` at the beginning of 
the trigger. However, by doing that we override the default behaviour of SQL dealing with errors in triggers.

**My question is if I do that does it expose any issue to the system?**

Any other solution except for stripping the trigger off logic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your catch statement, you are inserting and issuing a rollback. it should be the other way around. no need to change the `XACT_ABORT`

Comment: @ughai, The thing is that as soon as SQL generates the error in the trigger because of that setting the transaction gets doomed and I have found no way to resolve it unless we turn off that switch. I don't care about what I am doing in the catch block, I just need to keep my transaction alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your transaction alive, `XACT_ABORT = OFF` should help.

However setting `XACT_ABORT = OFF` doesn't guarantee that the transaction continues in all cases. It is dependent on severity of the error.

> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.

Another issue with `XACT_ABORT = OFF` is that now your error handling and the process of data which is persisted is different across code with different `XACT_ABORT` setting.

**EDIT**

These links may help.

[Why TRY CATCH does not suppress exception in trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/why-try-catch-does-not-suppress-exception-in-trigger)

[Ignoring errors in Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971602/ignoring-errors-in-trigger)

Comment: well i dont still get the answer. but i dont think i will get any better. to me it implicitly means you can not put any logic code or some important stuff in the trigger which based on our architecture it does not suit us.