# SQL Server throws error in trigger "Transaction doomed in trigger. Batch has been aborted."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
insert into tuseractivitytrack (TrackIndustryId,tracktype) values(null,'news')
```

When I insert a null value to a column it gives error now what i have done i have put the code of substring in try catch block but still if a error generated it generate a error     and the rows does'nt get inserted

Comment: If there's an error in the *trigger*, we almost certainly need to see the *code* in the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use savepoint inside trigger rather than transaction. Can you please provide code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(v=SQL.90).aspx

[TSQL: Try-Catch Transaction in Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884334/tsql-try-catch-transaction-in-trigger)